# How to join two tables that has one to many relationship in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, spring-cloud-gcp-bigquery

Let say I have student Table like below in BigQuery:

[image: Student Table]

Mark Table looks like below in Big Query:

[image: mark table]

I would like to join this two tables and create a new table like below  :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below query,

```sql
SELECT s.*, m.Mark_Details
  FROM student_table s
  JOIN (
    SELECT student_ID,
           STRING_AGG('' || Subject_ID || ':' || Subject_Name || ':' || Mark, ' | ') AS Mark_Details
      FROM mark_table
     GROUP BY 1
  ) m USING (student_ID)
```